# PHP value being replaced with 'yes'

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm calling some property information, and for some items, replacing the value that comes through (ie. if Yes, replace it with qTranslate code for multi-langauages & the same for 'No').

For some reason, the item before the 1st thing that has a replaced value (Terrace Size) isn't showing the number value, but instead shows 'yes'. This isn't anywhere in the file, and the value on the other end is 30 (differs per property).

This is that section of the PHP:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'terracesize',true) && $terracesize): ?>
            <li>
                <p><?php echo PROP_TRRCESIZE_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php _e( $terracesize ); ?> <?php echo TRRCESIZE_UNIT_CSTM;?></p>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true) && $property_pool):
$property_pool_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_pool',true);
if ($property_pool_meta == 'Yes') {
    $property_pool_meta = '<!--:en-->Yes<!--:--><!--:es-->Sí<!--:--><!--:ru-->да<!--:-->';
}
elseif ($property_pool_meta == 'No') {
    $property_pool_meta = '<!--:en-->No<!--:--><!--:es-->No<!--:--><!--:ru-->нет<!--:-->';
} ?>
<li>
    <p><?php echo PROP_POOL_CSTM;?>:</p><p> <?php _e( $property_pool_meta ); ?></p>
</li>
```

(I've included the next item, for Pool).

Here's the full code for this page: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8043189 (line 243)

This is [the site](http://vetromar.com/beta/property/cabo-roig-villa/)

Comment: What it means > Yes, replace it with qTranslate code for mulch-langauages & the same for 'No'.

Comment: What's in `$terracesize`? Where is it set? What do you see if you `var_dump($terracesize)`?

Comment: I've managed to sort this in the end, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using: `<?php _e( $terracesize ); ?>`

When actually, I should have been using: `<?php _e( $post->ID,'terracesize' ); ?>`